# GO for loop object assignment

Tags: r

I am using RStudio and have this code:

```
My_Iterator<-mget(x=c('X','Y','Z','X_Y','X_Z','Y_Z','X_Y_Z'))
 for (i in My_Iterator) {
 EzID<- unique(i[['Entrez.ID']])
 geneList       <-factor(as.integer(AllHumanGenes %in% EzID))
 names(geneList)<-AllHumanGenes

My_Names<-c('A_GO','B_GO','C_GO','A_B_GO','A_C_GO','B_C_GO','A_B_C_GO')
 for (i in 1:length(My_Names)){
 My_Iterator[My_Names[i]] <-new(Class   ='topGOdata',          
                 ontology='BP', 
                 allGenes=geneList, 
                 annot   =annFUN.org,
                 mapping ='org.Hs.eg.db')
 }
break;
}
```

I added in the break; b/c otherwise it would not stop looping. The problem that I am now having is that after it loops through the appropriate 7 times, it still only spits out one object, where I need it to spit out 7 different objects (A_GO, B_GO, etc.). If all is say is:

```
My_Iterator<-mget(x=c('X','Y','Z','X_Y','X_Z','Y_Z','X_Y_Z'))
 for (i in My_Iterator) {
 EzID<- unique(i[['Entrez.ID']])
 geneList       <-factor(as.integer(AllHumanGenes %in% EzID))
 names(geneList)<-AllHumanGenes

 My_Iterator[i] <-new(Class   ='topGOdata',          
                 ontology='BP', 
                 allGenes=geneList, 
                 annot   =annFUN.org,
                 mapping ='org.Hs.eg.db')
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in My_Iterator[i] <- new(Class = "topGOdata",  : 
 incompatible types (from S4 to character) in subassignment type fix
```

I have also tried this:

```
My_Names[i] <- My_Iterator[My_Names[i]] <-new(Class   ='topGOdata',          
                   ontology='BP', 
                   allGenes=geneList, 
                   annot   =annFUN.org,
                   mapping ='org.Hs.eg.db')
}
 break;
}
```

And get the same error:

```
Error in My_Names[i] <- My_Iterator[My_Names[i]] <- new(Class = "topGOdata",  : 
  incompatible types (from S4 to character) in subassignment type fix
```

I'm sure it's just a simple fix, but I am not coming up with it. PLEASE HELP!

P.s. Sorry if I am not using the correct terminology. Hope you can still understand what I am asking!

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? We don't have your data nor your functions, so going through this will be unnecessarily tedious.

Comment: You're doing lots of dangerous things: using `i` as an iterator in both loops, changing the contents and possibly the length of `My_Iterator` in the inside loop, for two glaring examples.  Now, the error message is clear: why have you made one of your variables S4 but not the others?